# Sound recorder not working

Tags: 16.04, soundcard, audio-recording, sound-recorder

I turned on the recorder, and said "Hello..Hellloo...Hello", and the output is [this](https://nofile.io/f/v7MjApv8gNX/rec_4s.mp3). I tried various sound recorders, and the output is same. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

How do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in a headphone/earphone first. Then, go to `System Settings >Sound >Input`then increase the `Input Volume`.

Comment: Tried, and still the same.

Comment: Can you play other sounds like music and all?

Comment: Yes, I can.....

Comment: Check this [help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Line_Input.2FMicrophone_Troubleshooting]